# How to set embedded tomcat jvmroute

Tags: spring-boot

I need to set the jvmRoute used by Spring Boot's embedded tomcat, but it looks like the only easy way I can do this is by passing in a jvm argument, e.g: **-DjvmRoute=myroute**

I'd rather set this property in application.properties. Is the jvm argument my only option, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with to solve my problem. Since the org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine sets the jvmRoute based on a System property, I simply get my own tomcat.jvmroute property from application.properties, and set it as a System property in a @Configuration file:

```
@Configuration
public class TomcatConfig {
    @Value("${tomcat.jvmroute}")
    private String jvmRoute;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setJvmRoute() {
        // embedded tomcat uses this property to set the jvmRoute
        System.setProperty("jvmRoute", jvmRoute);
    }
}
```